# Unsupported Get Request - Retrieve Post/Comments/Likes - Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a post using the https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed API endpoint, but when I attempt to retrieve anything related to that post all I get is an "Unsupported get request" error. The same access token us being used for both creating and retrieving the post, which according to the [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post#readperms) should work since it was used to create the post in the first place.

I'm using the python requests package to retrieve the data:

```
r = requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/" + share_id, 
                 params={'access_token': access_token})
```

This is the post ID that's being used if that helps anything: 10153657006856289_10153776085521289

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/468834489955818

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much. I was smashing my head against this problem for a couple hours yesterday and was so confused as to why my code from Monday had stopped working yesterday.